# "Unexpected token error: :" on Safari wth jQuery mobile 1.4.5

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, safari

I have the following html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
hi
</body>
</html>
```

In Safari 9.0.2, I get an `Unexpected token error: :` at line 3753 in the `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js` file.

I don't get an error in Chrome.